# AdonisJS exists Validator

Tags: adonis.js, indicative

I'm following the official [documentation] (https://legacy.adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/validator) && [indicative](https://indicative.adonisjs.com/guides/master/introduction#indicative-extending), but I couldn't find anything to help me.

I want to validate **if the given param exists on database**.

So I tried:

*app/Validators/myValidator*

```
const { rule } = use('Validator')

get rules () {
    return {
      userId: 'required|integer|exists:MyDatabase.users,userId', <-- this is what isn't working
      date: [
        rule('date'),
        rule('dateFormat', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      ]
    }
  }

// Getting the data to be validated
  get data () {
    const params = this.ctx.params

    const { userId, date } = params

    return Object.assign({}, { userId }, { date })
  }
```

It gives me the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "select * from `MyDatabase`.`users`.`userId` where `undefined` = '2' limit 1 - ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`userId` where `undefined` = '2' limit 1' at line 1",
    "name": "ErrorValidator",
    "status": 40
  }
}
```

How should I properly indicate that I want to compare `MyDatabase.users.userid` to the given parameter?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hard try/error I stumbled upon the solution.
Just need to follow what is inside `hooks.js` and pass the values separated by comma, like so:

```js
get rules () {
  return {
    userId: 'required|integer|exists:MyDatabase,MyTable,columntoCompare',      
  }
}
```